# How to remap a regular key into a modifier key (Shift...) in Linux

Tags: keyboard, xkb, xmodmap

On my new laptop keyboard, there's a strange key next to my shift key. Frankly it's useless to me and having a shorter shift key doesn't let me reach some of the combinations that I was used to. I'd like to turn it that key into a left shift as well so that I have one long left shift again.

[image: weird layout]

First I've tried xmodmap according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297728/how-can-i-change-an-underutilized-keyboard-key-into-a-modifier-key), and same as him, I've had no success.

Then I tried to create a new xmodmap config by copying the entry of the left shift key into the strange key's row. Applying the settings however took very long (>10s) so having that in my bashrc was not an option, since it made opening new terminal tabs take way too long. It also didn't work in X either, only terminals. I also read that xmodmap is mostly considered outdated.

Lastly I tried to use xkb but frankly couldn't really figure out how according to entries on the Arch wiki and here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remap scancodes to keycodes with udev, this works whether you are using xorg, wayland or the virtual console.

The scan code can be obtained with the `evtest` command. Select your keyboard when `evtest` ask for device to scan, and press the key you want to remap. Here is a sample output when <kbd>alt</kbd> key is pressed

```
Event: time 1688218985.587133, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1688218985.587133, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
```

Then create an hwdb file that maps scancodes to keycodes in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d`.

This file remaps <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>, for example.

```bash
# generic keyword
evdev:input:b0003v*p*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=shift
```

Finally, run the following command to apply the change.

```bash
systemd-hwdb update
udevadm trigger
```

See [Map scancodes to keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) for detailed instructions and more examples.

#### Note:

- If you have an AT keyboard, use `evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*` to match your keyboard.
- A list of input event code can be found from header [linux/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h)

Comment: Whoa, that's exactly it. Thank you. Initially I thought that it was not working, then I noticed that while `evtest` reported the scancode in decimal, hwdb expects it in hexa. 

This is therefore a working solution to my problem:
`KEYBOARD_KEY_56=leftshift`

Answer (score 0):

@memchr's answer was a good start but it wasn't clear enough to me

I don't know all intricacies of the configuration. In the end, that's just what worked for me.

- `sudo touch /etc/udev/hwdb.d/mx-keys.hwdb` - create a config file (you can name your file anything you like as long as it has `.hwdb` extension)
- `sudo evtest` - select your keyboard (install `evtest` if needed).
  Press the key you want to remap (in my case, <kbd>></kbd> key next to left <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and you will receive the similar output

```
Event: time 1692951945.797570, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70064
Event: time 1692951945.797570, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 86 (KEY_102ND), value 1
```

- `sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/mx-keys.hwdb` - open config file in the editor

This is the content of my file

```
evdev:name:Logitech MX Keys:*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70064=leftshift
```

Let's break it down

- `Ligitech MX Keys` - name of my keyboard, you can copy it from the list of devices in `evtest`

For the next line we will use the output on key press from `evtest`

- `70064` - value of the key you want to remap. Take it from the end of the first line
- `leftshift` - value of the key you want to remap to. Take it from the second line, for me it was `KEY_LEFTSHIFT`

After that save the file and run these commands to apply the changes

```
systemd-hwdb update
udevadm trigger
```

In case you did everything right, the key will work right away, no need to restart the computer

Additional source: [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/k3h9qv/remapping_keys_using_hwdb_files/)